# Trouble with ArrayList in NetBeans7.2

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist

I'm new to Java, but I'm loving it!

I'm using NetBeans7.2, and when I try to create an ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

NetBeans says "type ArrayList does not take parameters" (which doesn't make sense, as my code is simple and seams to be correct for Java7).

Also, when I try to import:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

NetBeans says "ArrayList is already defined in this compilation unit".

It's not necessary to import ArrayList anymore?

Thank you very much! Please, forgive my bad english ;)

EDIT: Here is my full code (it's just an exercice)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ArrayList {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      ArrayList<String> cores = new ArrayList<>();
      cores.add("Branco");
      cores.add(0, "Vermelho");
      cores.add("Amarelo");
      cores.add("Azul");
      System.out.println(cores.toString());

      System.out.println("Tamanho= " + cores.size());
      System.out.println("Elemento2= " + cores.get(2));
      System.out.println("Indice Branco= " + cores.indexOf("Branco"));

      cores.remove("Branco");

      System.out.println("Tem Amarelo?" + cores.contains("Amarelo"));

   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? I don't have those problems in my pc.

Comment: What version of Java are you compiling with?

Comment: You don't have a conflicting type defined, do you?  What if you try `java.util.ArrayList<String> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>();`?

Comment: Change the name of your class. The compiler is confused about which ArrayList do you want to use.

Comment: Thank you all for the fast response!My Java and NetBeans are fully updated (a few minutes ago!). I've tried the "Clean & Build Project", and it returns exactly the same errors I described...

Comment: Btw. it should be better to write List<String> cores = new ArrayList<String>();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change the class name to something other than ArrayList, your code would be absolutely correct in Java7, where it is legitimate to use the diamond operator (`<>`) like you do:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

The basic idea behind this is so that code which instantiates generic classes can become less verbose. The Java7 compiler implies what is needed automatically.

Java6 will complain and require that you write it the way Jon suggested.

Comment: Precisely! That's what madth3 said in the comments, which solved my problem, but your answer is even more precise! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Keep in mind that if you have Java7 installed on your system, with Netbeans it is very simple to change the source format to whatever version you wish. Right click your project, go "Properties", go to "Sources" and use the "Source/Binary Format" combo-box in order to choose.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do:

```
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And it should work fine!

Comment: No, it's not necessary in Java7, wich automatically understands the <String> repeating. The correct answer came from madth3 in the comments: my class name was ArrayList, and that confused the compiler. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Change the *class name* if you named it as "**ArrayList**".